# Continuity of an identity linear transformation between two spaces.

Tags: functional-analysis

$V$ is a vector space of all continuous complex valued function on $ J = [a,b]$. Let $X_1 = (V,\|\|_{\infty})$ where $\|x\|_{\infty} = \max_{t \in J}\{x(t)\}$ and $X_2 = (V,\|\|_2)$ where $\|x\|_2 = <x,x>^{\frac{1}{2}}$. The the identity mapping $x \rightarrow x$ of $x_1$ onto $x_2$ is continuous. I want to prove it.

here $X_1$ is a normed linear space and $X_2$ is an inner product space. I have tried to use definition of the continuous function. Ordinary $\epsilon, \delta$ definition, definition of continuity using sequence and open set definition of continuity. But I can not match them with the data. Maybe some very easy point I am missing.

Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have $\| Id(x)\|_2 = \sqrt{\int_a^b x(t)^2 dt} \le \sqrt{\int_a^b \|x\|_\infty^2 dt} = \sqrt{b-a} \|x\|_\infty$, and so $\|Id\| \le \sqrt{b-a}$.

Comment: Thank you. I never imagine so easy it will be.

Comment: from where and why did the integration came???????????????????

Comment: The inner product is given by $\langle x, y \rangle = \sqrt{\int_a^b \bar{x}(t) y(t) dt}$.